# How to make a time system in a batch simulation game?

Tags: batch-file

I am creating a batch simulation game but I can't find a way to make a time system. I don't know how to revert it so it goes back to 0 o'clock when it hits 24 o'clock and to add 1 day (and I don't want it to be in real time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you are doing. Here are my two solutions:

1: If you want to write a program that does just that then you can write something like:

```
set /a clock=0

set /a days=0

:a

if %clock%==24 set /a days=days+1

if %clock%==24 set /a clock=0

set /a clock=clock+1

timeout 1 >nul

goto a
```

This will make the clock go up one every one second.

However, if you want to have this going on and still take user input
(because commands such as pause and set /p pause the entire script)

You could have another terminal running that saved the time as a .txt file

and after every user input it refreshes the time which I think would make you feel like your in more control but that is just my opinion.

To do this, you have a file that has the code from above, but before the goto a, write:

```
(

echo %clock%

echo %day%

) > time.txt
```

If you want to import the vaules, make sure the batch files are saved in the same place and switch the direction of the arrow >.

Comment: This should work just fine :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you work on a ["Hello World!"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program) program first. Then get familiar with a particular language and practice. Coding is like baking a cake; it takes practice until you can get it just right without the cookbook. You can start by looking up "'Hello World!' batch program," then look up variables and numbers. Coding takes lots of patience and motivation. But once you get the hang of it, it gets pretty dang fun. We were all here once. We were all new to this at one point, so I do not understand the downvotes.